# Source Code for SPO List is not Updating with New Column Name. Throwing Off JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list, calculated-column

This is for SharePoint Online

After changing the name of a column successfully (several days ago), the name of the column in the source codes still reflects the old column name. This is an issue because my JS is only working when I use the old column names. The source code is not updating to use the new name.

The column(s) that are not updating are calculated columns

I've though t about Deleting and remaking the column but having to reenter all the calculations for each column would take quite a while

Please ask me if you need more details on my problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a column / flied, SharePoint creates two names: the display name and the internal field name. By editing the name afterwards, you only modify the display name, but the internal fieldname stays the same. When programming against SharePoint you mostly use the internal fieldname and that's the likely explanation why you still need to use the 'old' field name.